# assembler hello world

Tags: ассемблер, gnu-assembler

Начал учить ассемблер и даже hello world не могу вывести...
у меня linux 64 разряда Ubuntu

Вопросы:

1. подскажите где брать регистры для разный систем
2. как написать hello world
3. почему не работает эта программа? (компилирую вот так: `gcc FirstProgram.s -o hello`)

   ```
   hello:
       .ascii "Hello, world!"

   .global main
   main:
       mov $4, %eax
       mov $1, %ebx
       mov $hello, %ecx
       mov $13, %edx
       syscall
       mov $0, %eax
       mov $0, %ebx
   ```
4. как правильно компилировать?

Comment: Лайфхак - пишете "Hello word!" на языке "Си", транслируете язык "Си" в ассемблер и рассматриваете листинг. :-)

Comment: а на c++ можно? если да то как?

Comment: На c++ так же, как и на "Си". Во всех современных компиляторах есть ключ "вывести ассемблерный листинг". Поглядите документацию к Вашему компилятору, поставьте этот ключ и получите ассемблерный листинг.

Comment: ааа! и типо для оптимизации что то поудалать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Набор регистров зависит от архитектуры процессора, а не от операционной системы. Для большинства десктопных компьютеров это x86. Если вы пишете под архитектуру x86, то доступный набор регистров и команд будет примерно одним и тем же. А вот программный интерфейс (API, грубо говоря набор доступных функций ОС) и бинарный интерфейс (ABI, грубо говоря способ вызова функций API и способ передачи параметров) для разных систем, разной "битности" - будут разными.
2. Я нашел такой пример (Linux, x86-64):

   ```
   .data
   msg:
     .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
     .set len, . - msg

   .text

   .globl _start
   _start:
     # write
     mov  $1,   %rax
     mov  $1,   %rdi
     mov  $msg, %rsi
     mov  $len, %rdx
     syscall

     # exit
     mov  $60, %rax
     xor  %rdi, %rdi
     syscall
   ```

   Собирается так:

   ```
   as --64 hello-syscall.s -o hello-syscall.o
   ld -melf_x86_64 -s hello-syscall.o -o hello-syscall
   ```

   **Источник: [Написание и отладка кода на ассемблере x86/x64 в Linux](https://eax.me/linux-assembler/)**
3. Я не углублялся в изучение ABI Linux, но похоже что syscall используется в 64-битном коде. У вас же, судя по регистрам (32-битные регистры `eax`, `ecx`, `edx` и т.д., но не 64-битные `rax`, `rcx`, `rdx`) - код 32-битный. Плюс способ вызова системной функции отличается от того, что я вижу по ссылке выше. Под какую систему ваш Hello World - трудно сказать, не настолько хорошо разбираюсь в вопросе. Проще у вас узнать, где вы взяли этот код.
4. Зависит от ассемблера, целевой системы, битности. Для вашего случая (ассемблер GAS, Linux, x86-64) - см. пример в п.2.